# How can I store a list of usernames on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a load of chat boxes which come up on click of a username within a list. The problem is  I need to know which are currently chosen to hide/show if more are clicked than there is screen space (think of facebook - you keep clicking friends for private message and when no more fit along the bottom, the next one takes the last boxes spot. Clearly you hide this last one, but want it to come back if you close this current choice)

So, I need to cache a list or have a ridiculous number of input boxes in preparation. I have been looking at possibilities and is it possible to implement this with JSON cache? Is there a better option?

If JSON is the best option, please can somebody show me simply:

-> store array of usernames in jquery to JSON cache
-> retrieve JSON cache into jquery array

My JSON knowledge = 0.0001% and this is the only thing I want to use it for for a long time so my jsfiddle attempts failed. If you know any good "beginner / fast skim over" tutorials please link them!

Many thanks as always

Comment: should the data persist once the browser is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should look into the HTML5 feature localStorage

[localStorage](http://css-tricks.com/localstorage-examples/)

[localStorage How to use it](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)

With that you can save the current username list of your users in their browser and access it easily with javascript.

You can save the data just for the browser session `sessionStorage` or for longer `localStorage`, so if the user comes back the next day, his settings will still be set.